# Stuttering scroll with GSAP in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, mobile-safari

I've been trying to put together something in jQuery as a replacer for [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io), that listens for a scroll event and plays through a [GSAP TimelineMax](https://greensock.com/timelinemax) based on the scroll position.

I've found a script that converts the scrolling position from `window` to percentages and then sets the position of the TimelineMax progress with this value. Basically, a hidden wrapper's (`#fake-height`) height is what's defining the speed of the animation. The higher I make the wrapper, the longer duration the animation will have. The animations then takes place in a fixed div (`#holder`).

Everything is working as expected in all the desktop browsers I've tried so far. However, when trying the code in iOS Safari, I'm experiencing a stuttering scroll. Almost like if the framerate of the animation gets lower overall than it should be. I'm having a feeling that this is not a performance issue, since the animation works flawlessly if I simply drag the scroll of the iPhone constantly with my finger on the screen the whole time, instead of swiping it (i. e. dragging and releasing my finger to create momentum).

**Code:**

```js
window.scrollTo(0, 0);

$(function() {

  var $window = $(window);
  var documentHeight = $(document).height();
  var windowHeight = $window.height();
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

  var timeline = new TimelineMax({
      paused: true
    })
    .to("#scene1 .top-left", 1.5, {
      x: -25,
      y: -25,
      rotation: 0.001
    }, "scene1Intro")
    .to("#scene1 .bottom-right", 1.5, {
      x: 25,
      y: 25,
      rotation: 0.001
    }, "scene1Intro")
    .to(".image-fullscreen", 1, {
      scale: 0.6,
      rotation: 0.001
    }, "scene1Intro+=0.5")
    .staggerTo("#scene1 .slide", 1, {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 2
    }, 1, "scene1Slides")
    .staggerTo("#scene1 .slide", 1, {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 3
    }, 1, "scene1Slides+=1")

  TweenMax.set(".slide", {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 1
  })

  TweenLite.defaultEase = Linear.easeNone;

  $window.on("resize", function() {
    windowHeight = $window.height();
  }).resize();

  $window.on("scroll", function() {
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scrollPercent = (scrollTop) / (documentHeight - windowHeight);
    timeline.progress(scrollPercent).pause()
  });

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #faded7;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#holder {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#fake-height {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 180vh;
}

.scene {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.frame-item {
  position: absolute;
}

.frame-inner {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease;
  transition: transform .1s ease;
  transition: transform .1s ease, -webkit-transform .1s ease;
}

#scene1 .top-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#scene1 .top-left .frame-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-image: url("http://tobiasgerhardsson.com/code/assets/top-left.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 196.72489%
}

#scene1 .bottom-right {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#scene1 .bottom-right .frame-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-image: url("http://tobiasgerhardsson.com/code/assets/bottom-right.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 147.10145%
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-fullscreen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.image-fullscreen img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-fullscreen">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/VrPzQ6Z3XK7oDcKn51AbKRAs_4U1wybryBOX62YhXXo3hVQLK9fujO_NtZ2hqUDs8e6KYicmew=w640-h400-e365" alt="">
</div>
<div id="holder">
  <section class="scene" id="scene1">
    <div class="frame">
      <div class="frame-item top-left">
        <div class="frame-inner"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="frame-item bottom-right">
        <div class="frame-inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">Test</div>
    <div class="slide">Test</div>
    <div class="slide">Test</div>
    <div class="slide">Test</div>
  </section>
</div>

<div id="fake-height"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

**Demo:** http://www.tobiasgerhardsson.com/code/

Any ideas on what might be causing this? If you try it on mobile, nevermind the strange behavior of the page jumping when reaching the end. I'll figure that out later.

Comment: "position: fixed;" and ios do not go together

Comment: Any thoughts on workarounds? Because it worked like a charm when I tried the same principle with ScrollMagic. So they must’ve solved it in some way.

Comment: I just found this via duckduckgo, haven't tried it. https://www.cssscript.com/lock-scrolling-web-page/